# TabView: Have some of the tabs on the left side, and some of them on the right (Space in between)

Tags: java, css, javafx, tabs, scenebuilder

I'm trying to create a TabView in JavaFX. I would like to have some of the tabs distanced from the other tabs, since their functions belong to another category.

This is what it looks like now:

[image: Platform]

And as you can see I want the two last tabs to be moved to the right side without affecting the rest.

Here's my FXML-file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ChoiceBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Tab?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TabPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.ColumnConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.RowConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>

<BorderPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="800.0" prefWidth="1000.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.171" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="Application.MainController">
   <center>
      <VBox alignment="BOTTOM_CENTER" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="100.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
         <children>a
            <TabPane accessibleRole="BUTTON" nodeOrientation="LEFT_TO_RIGHT" prefHeight="651.0" prefWidth="1000.0" tabClosingPolicy="UNAVAILABLE">
              <tabs>
                <Tab text="Courses">
                     <content>
                        <TableView prefHeight="665.0" prefWidth="1000.0">
                          <columns>
                            <TableColumn prefWidth="75.0" text="C1" />
                            <TableColumn prefWidth="75.0" text="C2" />
                          </columns>
                        </TableView>
                     </content>
                </Tab>
                <Tab text="Education Matrix">
                     <content>
                        <TableView prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0">
                          <columns>
                            <TableColumn prefWidth="75.0" text="C1" />
                            <TableColumn prefWidth="75.0" text="C2" />
                          </columns>
                        </TableView>
                     </content>
                </Tab>
                  <Tab text="Employee">
                    <content>
                      <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="200.0" />
                    </content>
                  </Tab>
                  <Tab text="Calendar">
                    <content>
                      <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="200.0" />
                    </content>
                  </Tab>
                  <Tab fx:id="companiesTab" text="Companies">
                    <content>
                      <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="200.0" />
                    </content>
                  </Tab>
                  <Tab fx:id="providerTab" text="Provider">
                    <content>
                      <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="200.0" />
                    </content>
                  </Tab>
              </tabs>
               <VBox.margin>
                  <Insets />
               </VBox.margin>
            </TabPane>
         </children>
      </VBox>
   </center>
   <bottom>
      <GridPane prefHeight="105.0" prefWidth="1000.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
        <columnConstraints>
          <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
            <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
          <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
        </columnConstraints>
        <rowConstraints>
          <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
        </rowConstraints>
         <children>
            <HBox alignment="CENTER_LEFT" prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="200.0" style="-fx-background-color: grey;">
               <children>
                  <Button mnemonicParsing="false" text="Button" />
               </children>
               <padding>
                  <Insets left="20.0" />
               </padding>
            </HBox>
            <HBox alignment="CENTER_RIGHT" prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="200.0" style="-fx-background-color: grey;" GridPane.columnIndex="2">
               <children>
                  <Button mnemonicParsing="false" text="Button" />
               </children>
               <opaqueInsets>
                  <Insets />
               </opaqueInsets>
               <padding>
                  <Insets right="20.0" />
               </padding>
            </HBox>
            <HBox alignment="CENTER" prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="200.0" style="-fx-background-color: grey;" GridPane.columnIndex="1">
               <children>
                  <Button mnemonicParsing="false" text="Button" />
               </children>
            </HBox>
         </children>
      </GridPane>
   </bottom>
   <top>
      <GridPane prefHeight="106.0" prefWidth="1000.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
        <columnConstraints>
          <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="494.0" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="289.0" />
          <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="711.0" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="711.0" />
        </columnConstraints>
        <rowConstraints>
          <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
        </rowConstraints>
         <children>
            <HBox alignment="CENTER_LEFT" prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="200.0">
               <children>
                  <ChoiceBox prefWidth="150.0" />
               </children>
               <padding>
                  <Insets left="20.0" />
               </padding>
            </HBox>
            <HBox alignment="CENTER" prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="200.0" GridPane.columnIndex="1">
               <children>
                  <Label text="Smart Academy Manager">
                     <font>
                        <Font name="Arial" size="31.0" />
                     </font>
                  </Label>
               </children>
            </HBox>
         </children>
      </GridPane>
   </top>
</BorderPane>`enter code here`
```

Comment: The standard controls have their limitations, this is one of them.  You'd need to create your own control or perhaps a different `Skin` for `TabView`, which can be quite a lot of effort.

Comment: Perhaps use colour coded tabs to differentiate categories rather than spacing them out. I feel like putting the tab to the right side would confuse the user...

Answer (score 2):

Original `TabPane` does not provide tools for custom tab layout. But a similar result can be obtained using some trick.

You can set invisible `Tab` into required place and bind it's width with width of the `TabPane`.

First we need to calc splitter's width. This is the width of the `TabPane` minus the sum of the widths of the `Tab`s, excluding the splitter. `Tab` object can be obtained as `Node` from `TabPane` using the command `.lookup()`. We also need to consider the width associated with the styles (padding, spacing). For this example I will set this number by hard (for default theme). After calcs we set size of the splitter using `.setStyle()`:

```
private void autoSizeSplitter(TabPane tabPane, Tab splitter) {
    double width = tabPane.getWidth();
    Set<Node> tabs = tabPane.lookupAll(".tab");
    for (Node node : tabs) {
        if (node.getId() == null || !node.getId().equals(splitter.getId())) {
            width = width - node.getBoundsInParent().getWidth();
        }
    }
    double PADDING = 20;
    width = width - PADDING;
    splitter.setStyle("-fx-background-color:transparent; -fx-pref-width: " + width + ";");
}
```

Finally we set the listener on the `TabPane` width property and autosize splitter for first time in initialization:

```
tabPane.widthProperty().addListener(observable -> autoSizeSplitter(tabPane, splitter));
Platform.runLater(() -> autoSizeSplitter(tabPane, splitter));
```

Full example:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Tab;
import javafx.scene.control.TabPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.util.Set;

public class Sample extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        TabPane tabPane = new TabPane();
        tabPane.setTabClosingPolicy(TabPane.TabClosingPolicy.UNAVAILABLE);

        Tab splitter = new Tab();
        splitter.setDisable(true);
        splitter.setId("splitter");

        tabPane.getTabs().add(new Tab("111"));
        tabPane.getTabs().add(new Tab("222"));
        tabPane.getTabs().add(splitter);
        tabPane.getTabs().add(new Tab("333"));
        tabPane.getTabs().add(new Tab("444"));
        tabPane.getTabs().add(new Tab("555"));

        Scene scene = new Scene(tabPane, 640, 480);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

        tabPane.widthProperty().addListener(observable -> autoSizeSplitter(tabPane, splitter));
        Platform.runLater(() -> autoSizeSplitter(tabPane, splitter));
    }

    private void autoSizeSplitter(TabPane tabPane, Tab splitter) {
        double width = tabPane.getWidth();
        Set<Node> tabs = tabPane.lookupAll(".tab");
        for (Node node : tabs) {
            if (node.getId() == null || !node.getId().equals(splitter.getId())) {
                width = width - node.getBoundsInParent().getWidth();
            }
        }
        double PADDING = 20;
        width = width - PADDING;
        splitter.setStyle("-fx-background-color:transparent; -fx-pref-width: " + width + ";");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: I use runlater sometimes when I want the code to be used after initializing view. This is sometimes useful.

Comment: it's a evil habit ;)